# Javascript switch, case, break doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html

I'm new at JS

I'm making a drum kit website and i create a switch section but it's not working.

```
var numberOfDrumButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".drum").length;

for (var i = 0; i < numberOfDrumButtons; i++) {

  document.querySelectorAll(".drum")[i].addEventListener("click", function() {


    var buttonInnerHtml = this.innerHTML;

    switch (buttonInnerHtml) {
      case "w":
        var tom1 = new Audio('songs/oni-chan.mp3');
        tom1.play();
        break;

      case "a":
        var tom2 = new Audio('songs/oni-chan2.mp3');
        tom2.play();
        break;

      case "s":
        var tom3 = new Audio('songs/oni-chan3.mp3');
        tom3.play();
        break;
      default:
        break;
    }

  })
}
```

HTML:

```
  <div class="set">
    <button class="w drum"><span>w</span></button>
    <button class="a drum"><span>a</span></button>
    <button class="s drum"><span>s</span></button>
    <button class="d drum"><span>d</span></button>
    <button class="j drum"><span>j</span></button>
    <button class="k drum"><span>k</span></button>
    <button class="l drum"><span>L</span></button>
  </div>

  <script src="index.js" href="UTF-8"></script>
```

Comment: What exactly does "it's not working" mean? Does *anything* happen? Are errors reported?

Comment: When i click the button, It should play audio

Comment: OK.... And what does it actually do?

Comment: nothing right now

Comment: The `innerHTML` would be `"<span>w</span>"` for the first button, not `"w"`. Use `textContent` instead.

Comment: WOW! It's true! Thank you so much Heretic Monkey :). You saved me. Well, i didn't know to add also span. Every minutes i learn someting

Comment: So, how can i close to question :D

Comment: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173)

Answer (score 2):

From the Audio docs(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement/Audio#determining_when_playback_can_begin):

There are three ways you can tell when enough of the audio file has loaded to allow playback to begin:

- Check the value of the readyState property. If it's HTMLMediaElement.HAVE_FUTURE_DATA, there's enough data available to begin playback and play for at least a short time. If it's HTMLMediaElement.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA, then there's enough data available that, given the current download rate, you should be able to play the audio through to the end without interruption.
- Listen for the canplay event. It is sent to the  element when there's enough audio available to begin playback, although interruptions may occur.
- Listen for the canplaythrough event. It is sent when it's estimated that the audio should be able to play to the end without interruption.
  The event-based approach is best:

```
myAudioElement.addEventListener("canplaythrough", event => {
  /* the audio is now playable; play it if permissions allow */
  myAudioElement.play();
});
```